# How do I combine 2 32-bit Unsigned Integers to 64-bit integer

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, endianness, unsigned

Lets say I got 2 unsigned integer 
 
first with value `&H0D345B40` 
second with value `&H9AF34A32`

How do I produce a unsigned 64 bit integer with the value
`&H324AF39A405B340D`

Here is what I tried

```
dim crypt1 as uint32 = &H0D345B40
dim crypt2 as uint32 = &H9AF34A32

Dim output As UInt64 = (CType(CType(crypt1, UInt64), Long) Or (crypt2 << 32))

the output is &H000000009FF75B72
```

Comment: Dim output = &H9AF34A320D345B40UL

Comment: Yeah but i need to combine 2 variables can't just use hand

Comment: Dim output As UInt64 = crypt2 * &h10000000 + crypt1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it a crappy way but not bad anyways

```
    dim output() as uint64
    Dim bytes() As UInteger = {crypt1, crypt2}

    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, output, 0, 8)
```